# Model learning times in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am quite new to r and machine learning in general and am trying to train a few different models using some data. The training data set consists of 4650 observations of 75 variables, including the target. With dummy variables, I'm guessing(didn't preprocess myself) the total variables come up to around 130. The target is an ordered factor with 3 levels. With rattle, I get 1-2 seconds for training a tree, 45-55 seconds for training random forest, and around 30 seconds with svm. But using the nnet package with caret, I ran this code for a neuralnet model:

```
nnet_grid<-expand.grid(.decay = c(.1, .01), .size = c(20, 30, 40, 50))
nnetfit<-caret::train(OUTPUT ~ ., data=hdtrain, method="nnet", 
                      maxit = 10000, tuneGrid = nnet_grid, MaxNWts=10000)
```

Its now been more than 36 hours and this is still running. Is this sort of time expected? I'm running this on an i7-2720QM @ 2.2GHz with 8gb memory.

Comment: You might want to change the `trControl` parameter to something other than the defaults for resampling. See `?trainControl` for more details in particular you might want to adjust the first few arguments.

Comment: No, there's something wrong.  But I would suggest using TensorFlow or Theano in python for neural network models.

Answer (score 0):

You have both `maxit` and `MaxNWts` set quite high - is there a reason you chose those numbers? I'd suggest trying it with the defaults first, of 100 and 1000, respectively, and potentially also decreasing the size of your parameter grid. Then increase the iterations and number of parameters once you get a run of that through.

From the [nnet documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/nnet.pdf) on `MaxNWts`:

> The maximum allowable number of weights. There is no intrinsic limit in the code, but **increasing MaxNWts will probably allow fits that are very slow and time-consuming**. (emphasis mine)

Comment: `maxit` is high because during previous individual runs I rarely saw the model converge before 4K iterations, sometimes converging after 8-9K. `MaxNWts` is at that number because with 50 neurons, 119 inputs (including dummies) and 3 output classes, the weights come out as 6103. Anyway the above code just wasn't stopping. I'm guessing `train` keeps running until all models converge. So after 72 hours, I stopped it, letting all that time go to waste.